# How to pause a timer run through SKAction in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

In my game built on SpriteKit the player has a set amount of time to complete each level, and on expiration either a game over method or a next level one is called.

Since I know that using `NSTimer` combined with SpriteKit is bad under different points of view, what I did in my `GameScene` is building the timer as a sequence of `SKActions` like this:

```
    private func runTimer(duration: TimeInterval) {
       let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
       let endLevel = SKAction.run { [weak self] in
          self?.handleEndLevel()
       }
       run(SKAction.sequence([wait, endLevel]), withKey: "timer")
}
```

Since I also have a pause button, which presents a `MenuScene`, and a resume button, what I'm trying to achieve is to pause/unpause the timer. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Here's what I already tried with no luck:

- set `GameScene` property `isPaused` to `true`.
- in `GameViewController`, setting the `pausesOutgoingScene` and `pausesIncomingScene` properties of `SKTransition` when presenting `GameScene`/`MenuScene`.
- introducing a `timerNode` to add as a child to the scene, then saying `timerNode.run` and setting its `isPaused` property.
- using `.speed` instead of `.isPaused`.

All of these lead to the same result: even if the game is paused and resumed, the timer runs as it was never paused, so ending the level before it is supposed to. Since I'm still learning SpriteKit, my understanding of the `isPaused` property is that it is used to determine wheter actions are performed, so I thought an already running action would be paused, this might be wrong on my part maybe tho.

I know there might be a drastic solution: I can call `removeAction(forKey: "timer")` on pause while storing the time at which it was removed, and with some calculation I can set up another timer with the amount of time left once the game is resumed. This looks not pretty and overcomplicated tho and I can't believe Apple did not implement something easier.

Comment: I don't think an `SKAction.wait` is the correct approach here.  You should use a `Timer` that ticks periodically and track the the remaining time to a computed end `Date`. When. you pause you record the remaining time.  When you resume you can use the saved remaining time to recompute the new end `Date`.  Check the `isPaused` flag in your Timer method so that it doesn't end the game while paused. Make sure you timer runs faster than once per second; I would suggest around 0.2s

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, can I ask you why it's not? Just to understand what am I doing, cause most of the people suggest to use SKAction.wait instead of timers when it comes to SpriteKit. Btw a timer was my original approach, but it impacts heavily on performance.

Comment: I think all of the problems you have listed in your question are why not - `SKAction.wait` is intended to control the behaviour of a sprite as part of its "script".  It isn't meant to control your overall game logic. I can't see how a timer running 5 times a second is going to have much impact on your app performance, unless you are doing a lot of work in its block, which you shouldn't need to; A quick elapsed time calculation and you're done.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It impacted because I actually had other timers for spawners and the game lagged sometimes. It runs smooth since i switched to SKAction.wait tho. I'll try some hybrid approach then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a debug, I found out that the issue lies in the fact that when the user taps the pause button I'm presenting another scene and I'm setting `gameScene.isPaused` to true in the `ViewController`. If I set the `isPaused` property in the `GameScene`, without presenting other scenes, the scene actually pauses. The reason of this behaviour is still unclear to me.

An important note, `SKAudioNodes` must be paused and resumed separately using `SKAction.pause`, otherwise the background music will pause but on resume there will be a (small) offset between the audio player state and the scene state.